# HTML Input to number and add

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make an input and whatever the number is there, to add it using a button. I cannot understand what my code miss and why is not adding the value from the input.

Do I need to convert to a number from a string or?

```js
let funds = document.getElementById("funds");
let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
let add = document.getElementById("add");
let base = 0;

function adauga() {
  funds.innerText = base += input;
}
```

```html
<p>Funds Available</p>
<p id="funds">0$</p>
<input id="input" type="number" class="text-black w-28 rounded-xl border-2 border-red-700" />
<button id="add" onclick="adauga()" class="ml-4 bg-red-700 px-3 py-1 rounded-xl">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

You should be using

```
let input = document.getElementById("input");
```

and get the current input value with

```
funds.innerText = (base+= input.valueAsNumber)+"$";
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this but it seems I have to convert from string to number. With your solution I got  020 (0 + 20 from input).

Comment: Yes - I temporarily forgot the `+` in front of `input.value` that makes it numeric.

Comment: Don’t use `+input.value`. Use `input.valueAsNumber`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for pointing that out! The property `.valueAsNumber` was new to me!

Comment: Except if you put anything in that input that isn't a number you'll get NaN. If you just use `Number(input.value)` you won't get that error.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues.

The first is, as you correctly pointed out, that the number needs to be coerced to a string.

The second is that you're immediately setting the value of `input` to that element's value rather than using the *new* value of the input box to change the text content. So pick up the value in the *function* instead.

```js
let funds = document.getElementById("funds");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let add = document.getElementById("add");

let base = 0;

function adauga() {
  funds.textContent = `${(base += Number(input.value))}$`;
}
```

```html
<p>Funds Available</p>
<p id="funds">0$</p>
<input id="input" type="number" class="text-black w-28 rounded-xl border-2 border-red-700" />
<button id="add" onclick="adauga()" class="ml-4 bg-red-700 px-3 py-1 rounded-xl">Add</button>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you! Worked exactly like I was looking for.
1 question tough, how it worked just Number() and not Number.parseInt() ?

Comment: [Because that's just how it works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) is different because it allows you to specify a radix to coerce the value to a specific base.